# Hibernate Search - Which fields do I annotate with @Facet when using field dot notation "a.b.c"

Tags: java, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

Hibernate Search 5.3+ requires @Facet annotation; our application makes use of field dot notation (e.g. `facetingRequest.onField("field.childField.grandchildField")`.

*Do I annotate @Facet on the leaf field (grandchild); the first field (child) or every field in the dot notation chain?*

Answer (score 0):

You would annotate the actual leave node. Have you actually just tried or why do you ask the question.

Comment: Documentation on Hibernate Search faceting annotations for dot notated fields is sparse. For good reason it turns out; there's a [open bug](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-1927) for `@Facet` with `@IndexEmbedded`. Unless I'm mistaken, developers with similar denormalised field notation will need pin themselves to Hibernate 5.2.1 or lower until the bug is resolved.

Comment: HSEARCH-1927 is actually of a limitation of the underlying Lucene implementation and only applied in the case of *ToMany associations where numeric values get indexed/faceted. Note prior to 5.3 this type of faceting on collection based associations was not possible at all. Now it works at least for string encoded fields. Depending on your usecase you might be able to use FacetEncodingType.STRING and encode the facet values as strings, but of course it implies discrete faceting requests. To fix HSEARCH-1927, Lucene must first provide a solution of the problem on their side.

Comment: I see, that is interesting. Our existing code does facet on denormalised xToMany numeric entity id fields; I guess it must be doing something quite different under the hood in 5.2 and lower. Do you know the Lucene Jira ticket for their side of the fence?